# Sources for Geo-referenced data for Tiger populations in India or other countries

Tags: data, open-source-gis, india

I'm currently an Undergrad student in a GIS class, and I'm trying to conduct some research on tiger populations and urbanization. Does anyone know where I might be able to find data for tiger populations?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of data do you want? Occurrence grids, point data (sightings?) or range polygons?

For the latter one you could have a look on and download spatial data here:
http://maps.iucnredlist.org/map.html?id=15955